# count unique for field in crosstab query

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I've searched for an answer to this, but can't seem to find anything that works to do a unique count in crosstabs. The closest I could find was: select count(myField) from (select distinct myField from myTable), but I keep getting errors.

The training type is in columns, the dates in rows (formatted to month so I can separate out quarters or individual months), and ideally I would have the values as number of unique trainees that are identified by their Grower Record IDs. It currently displays all trainees who have been to the same training multiple times.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Below is the SQL. Thanks for your time!

SQL:

```
TRANSFORM Count([TDB - Master - Trainee Attendence].[Grower Record ID]) AS [CountOfGrower Record ID]
SELECT Format([Dat Fòmasyon],'mm/yy') AS Months, Count([TDB - Master - Trainee Attendence].[Grower Record ID]) AS [Total Of Grower Record ID]
FROM [TDB - Master - Trainee Attendence]
WHERE (((Format([Dat Fòmasyon],'mm/yy'))="01/13" Or (Format([Dat Fòmasyon],'mm/yy'))="02/13"))
GROUP BY Format([Dat Fòmasyon],'mm/yy')
PIVOT [TDB - Master - Trainee Attendence].[Tit Fòmasyon an];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you create a query of the data you want to report (presumably):

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Grower Record ID], [Dat Fomasyon], [Tit Fomasyon an]
FROM [TDB - Master - Trainee Attendance]
```

Then generate a pivottable using this query as the data source.

Now I am not completely familiar with access's nuances, and dont know for certain that you can generate a pivottable from a query, but if not, I'd suggest changing your code (in a clone of the form) to do the same thing, replacing the from clause with a [aliased] query (and removing the references to the base table appearing in other clauses):

```
TRANSFORM Count([Grower Record ID] AS [CountOfGrower Record ID]
SELECT Format([Dat Fomasyon], 'mm/yy' AS Months, Count([Grower Record ID]) as [Total of Grower Record ID]
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [Grower Record ID], [Dat Fomasyon], [Tit Fomasyon] 
      FROM [TDB - Master - Trainee Attendance]) Uniq
WHERE Format([Dat Fòmasyon],'mm/yy') = "01/13" Or Format([Dat Fòmasyon],'mm/yy' = "02/13"
GROUP BY Format([Dat Fòmasyon],'mm/yy')
PIVOT [Tit Fòmasyon an]
```

Note, I couldnt help thinking while rewriting the logic that it has been editted since being generated, as the name of the count (in [] after "AS") is different in the transform and select lines. I wouldnt expect this to matter, though in access you never know.

Hope this helps...

Please mark as answer if this helps you.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the response! I tried the first query, which effectively displays a list of a grower (farmer) ID with a date and the title of a training module.  However, I'm trying to find a unique count of grower IDs by training and month. So for a given month, I want to know how many unique individuals attended the training. This is complicated by the fact that growers attended the same training within a month on different days. So the table, TDB - Master, has columns with grower IDs, dates of trainings, and titles of trainings.

Comment: Also, wanted to add that I tried the second query, which is still counting growers multiple times across the same training they attended multiple times within a given month...  Thanks again for your help. Any other thoughts?